# Jetty 9 adding charset by default

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

Jetty 9 is adding charset by default to the "content-type" in the response headers. Is there a way to avoid this default behavior?

Content-Type : application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8

Thank you!!!

PS:

Comment: Which exact version of Jetty 9 are you using?

Comment: Also, what are you doing / requesting when you see that?